# How to write a regular expression to find the line starts with at least one word

Tags: regex, grep

How to find the line that starts with at least one dog from the following lines

```
-catdogcat [pass]
-dog------ [pass]
-catdoglol dog [pass]
-catcatcat dog [fail]
```

I wrote `/^-(dog){1,3}/` but it certainly doesn't work when the input is `'-catdogcat'`

Comment: Why is the second example considered a fail?

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake,the second should be considered as pass

Comment: @AisenWang, did you take a look at my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^-\S*dog/
```

The idea is to start with a dash, followed by any amount of non-whitespace characters, followed by a `dog`.

---

If you want to ensure that each word should be 3 characters long, you could be more explicit:

```
/^-(\S{3})*dog/
```

---

And if you want each word to be 3 characters long and everything to start with three words, you can be even more explicit:

```
/^-(\S{3}){0,2}dog/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!One more question,what if we define a word must be 3 words.i.e. '-cadogmeow' would fail because none of 'cad', 'ogm', 'eow' matches 'dog'

Comment: @AisenWang, you mean you want to ensure that each word is 3 characters long?

Comment: /^-(...)*dog/ doesnt work when '-catdogcat atdog',So I found ^-(\S{3})*dog